# How do I properly add a "Connection : close" header to an Http request?

Tags: http, header, connection, request

I keep getting an error when I'm adding the "Connection : close" header to an Http request...
The error is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'content' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3601)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
```

The reason for this error is that the web server returns a very long (larger than MAX_LONG) response for the request (to which I added the "Connection : close" header) and so the data base is collapsing because it exceeds the size of data allowed for that column (the content of the request). If I leave out this header, the responses are just fine and with reasonable length.

Anybody got a clue?

tnx, Itamar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the server is HTTP 1.0 and doesn't handle the "Connection : close" header correctly? Perhaps you forgot a CRLF after one of your headers or perhaps you forgot the blank line that indicates the end of the headers.
Anyway, the general structure for a HTTP request is:
    initial line CRLF(=new line "carriage-return line-feed")
    header lines, each followed be a CRLF (>=0)
    a blank line (i.e. a CRLF by itself)
    [optional] message body (e.g. a file, or query data, or query output).
[quick http guide](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)